# I got a Google indexing warning because I am using HTTP forwarding

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, apache, google-index, linux

Today I received a mail from Google. There is a problem with indexing my website because I am using HTTP forwarding.

I disabled HTTP a week ago now only allowing HTTPS. I am using this code in my index.php:

```php
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
    {
      header("Location: https://url.to.my.site");
      return;
    }
```

This is fine and I know it only affects the index.php (not any other files).

I am very sure the Google warning comes from this.

What can I do to get rid of the Google warning? Or should I simply ignore the mail?

If someone here says I should use a `.htaccess` file instead then please say **why** that will fix the warning.

The message id of the email is WNC-10030322.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us if you are on windows or *nix.  Are you running IIS or Apache ?  And more of the error message.  Finally, all pages have to https, not just index.php

Comment: It's a Linux web server. As I said I only want to force HTTPS for index.php.

Comment: It's an Apache.

Comment: Can I ask why you only want index.php as https and not others ?

Comment: @RohitGupta I have a client which does not support HTTPS (an Arduino) connecting to other parts of the website. Are you sure the reason for the Google error is that I am still allowing HTTP for other files than index.php?

Comment: Its either that or too many redirects.  I have never done it this way or used mix content.  I dont want to plagiarize, so have a read of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106313/redirecting-from-http-to-https-with-php), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583461/redirect-to-page-and-send-custom-http-headers). and [3](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71512/is-it-possible-to-force-a-browser-to-use-http-in-an-ssl-enabled-https-website)

Comment: Is your HTTPS site fully working with a valid security certificate?  Can you see stats about the HTTPS version of your site in Google Search Console?  (Either a domain property or a `http://` prefix property)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know I had my website added as "http://my.web.site" and not as HTTPS. I removed the HTTP property and added the website as HTTPS. I did this in the Google search console.

Now when Google crawls my website it won't get any redirect because it's already at HTTPS.

I am quite sure this solves my problem.

Comment: You may want to add both versions to Google search console. That will give you more visibility, especially transition from HTTP to https.